# Rails API: as_json with includes query the DB despite previous includes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I am struggling to find the best way to render records. So far, I did it the following way but, despite having includes when I fetch the main object, I get tons of DB queries when calling `as_json` for the child record that was included. What am I missing? Is there even a better way too do what I want to do?

I don't see how to have a better render since I want to decide what attributes and methods to serialise and use custom scopes on arrays of associate records.

- My controller

```rb
def show
  # The include below seems to be useless, the DB is queried again on render.
  @grandParent = GrandParent.includes(parents: { children: %i[grand_children friends] })
    .find_by_name(params[:name])

  return head :not_found unless @grandParent

  render json: grand_parent_as_json, status: :ok
end

private

def grand_parent_as_json
  json = @grandParent.as_json(
    only: %i[attr1 attr2],
    methods: %i[meth1 meth2]
  )
  # I don't see a better way to render it since I want to use a custom scope on parents
  json[:parents] = @grandParent.parents.ordered_by_birthdate(:desc).map do |parent|
    parent_as_json parent
  end
 
  json
end

# The include below seem to be the one responsible for querying the DB again.
def parent_as_json(parent)
  parent.as_json(
    only: %i[attr1 attr2],
    methods: %i[meth1 meth2],
    include: [
      children: {
        only: %i[attr1 attr2],
        include: [
          grand_children: { %i[attr1 attr2] }
        ]
      }
    ]
  )
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty sure there is a more elegant way to fix this but the issue is indeed the scope being used here:

```
@grandParent.parents.ordered_by_birthdate(:desc)
```

The reason being is the scope is guaranteed to return a new ActiveRecord::Relation which when accessed hits the DB.

It may not be the best answer but it will work by changing your initial query, to include an `.order` for the `birthdate` field.

```
@grandParent = GrandParent
  .includes(parents: { children: %I[grand_children friends] })
  .order("parents.birthdate DESC")
  .find_by_name(params[:name])
```

Then remove the `.ordered_by_birthdate` as you map the parent objects as they are already in the order you wanted. This has the disadvantage not using the scope `ordered_by_birthdate`  defined on `Parent`. This might be ok depending on how you view responsibilities of controller vs model.

Alternatively the above code snippet could also be part part of a scope on `GrandParent` e.g.

```
class GrandParent
  scope :family_tree, -> { includes(parents: { children: %I[grand_children friends] }).order("parents.birthdate DESC") }
end
```

Then you could do:

```
GrandParent.family_tree.find_by_name(params[:name])
```

Comment: I didn't think about the scope doing the includes, I'm going to check this out, thanks. In fact, the ordering scope is ordering on another associated table's attribute.

Comment: Yeah in my example it orders the associated parents by their birth date. Is that what you want to happen?

Comment: I took that example to make it simpler to understand. As I said, it's associated to another table. Let's say, for the sake of this example, that the birthdate is in the `birthday_events` table associated to parent. It should be ordered this way: `parents.birthday_events.date DESC`.